# SSI variable used in an Include?

Tags: html, url-rewriting, ssi

**Context:**

I am using Server Side Includes to collate a number of .shtml pages together to form a single page. These files include headers, footers, etc. General #include statements I am using -where I explicitly name the included file- work fine, such as `<!--#include virtual="/framework/parts/head.shtml" -->`.

I am using the following line in an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/parts/shell.shtml?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This makes it to that when I load a page the shell.shtml file loads instead. This works as expected.

My goal is to have a single shell.shtml file that is called and used as the framework for every single .html file/page on the site, which then uses SSI #includes to populate the contents of the page that loads.

**Existing Code:**

If I strip down shell.shtml to the following, it demos the issue I am having. This code lives in the `<body>` of the file:

```
  URI: <!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" --><br>
  Doc: <!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_NAME" --><br><br>
  
  Echo the value of the variable <b>DOCUMENT_URI</b>, which is this page's URL: <i><!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" --></i>. <br><br>
  
  <!--#include virtual="DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

**Current Result:**

This creates a page with the following:

> URI: /private/index.html
>
> Doc: shell.shtml
>
> Echo the value of the variable **DOCUMENT_URI**, which is this page's URL: */private/index.html*.
>
> [an error occurred while processing this directive]

**Question:**

What do I need to do to pass the value of the system variable DOCUMENT_URI into the #Include, such that the contents of the file /private/index.html are included?

Additionally, I have found that even if I manually write out the final #include, not relying on any variables at all that it still throws that same error, so I believe this is somehow tied to the htaccess rewrites in some manner.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `$` to the reference. From:

```
 <!--#include virtual="DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

to:

```
<!--#include virtual="$DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

Comment: Although $DOCUMENT_URI does work under normal circumstances, the .htaccess file causes this to break.